# Deny for everyone EXCEPT these TWO IPs

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to send everyone to a maintenance page EXCEPT the developers. I can successfully redirect ONE IP using a statement such as:

```
if ($remote_addr != IPHERE) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenanance.html;
}
```

however I can't figure out a way to add a second IP to the equation.

Any help with be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GEO module here is reference  https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html

```
geo $devguys {
  ip1/32 1;
  ip2/32 1;
}

server {
  if ($devguys) {
    rewrite ^ http://<your url>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that only to receive the 'not allowed here' errors, even though I have ngx_http_geo installed :/

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
location ~* /system/maintenanance.html {
        allow <dev_guys_ip_here>;
        deny all;
    }
```

I found this solution here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: I want to direct everyone to 'server_name' except for two ips that'll go to /system/maintenance.html. How can I implement it using 'location'? From what I'm understanding, the ruling should be IP-based, not location-based.